# Need help reusing ScalikeJDBC caller's transaction in method returning Akka stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, scalikejdbc

I am not able to reuse ScalikeJDBC caller's session in a method that returns Akka stream.

I am trying to write a class for database access that returns `Source` for use in Akka streaming application.

The following code works:

```
def retrieveMembers(): Source[Member, NotUsed] =
    val publisher: DatabasePublisher[Member] =  DB readOnlyStream { Member.streamAll }
    Source.fromPublisher(publisher)
```

However, this method creates its own transaction, so I wanted to follow up the recommendations here: [AutoSession](http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/auto-session.html) and changed the method to:

```
def retrieveMembers()(implicit session: DBSession = AutoSession): Source[Member, NotUsed] =
    val publisher: DatabasePublisher[Member] =  session readOnlyStream { Member.streamAll }
    Source.fromPublisher(publisher)
```

But, this does not work, because `readOnlyStream` is not defined for DBSession, only for DB.

How can I change my method so that it can reuse the caller transaction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know Scalike but isn't the `session` an implicit parameter of a method of `DB` or something like that?

Comment: DB implements the `LoanPattern` so it creates and closes `session`